# How to migrate resources from one account to another account on Azure Cloud without interrupting running services?

Tags: azure

I already have a personal account in Azure Cloud. There are 2 VMs and an AKS cluster under the account. I want to migrate the resources under the personal account to the company account. What should I do to comply with best practices? How can we ensure that the services running on the vm are not interrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such as a live migrate in Azure.

1. First you need to prepare the correct resources in the target subscription. Ensure that necessary resources (VNETs, storage accounts, etc.) are created in the target subscription, matching the configuration of the source subscription.
2. Use the Azure CLI or Azure Portal to export the configuration of your AKS cluster in the source subscription. This includes details such as node pools, networking configurations, and service principals.

   `az aks show --resource-group <source-resource-group> --name <aks-cluster-name> --subscription <source-subscription-id> --query "{name:name,location:location,resourceGroup:resourceGroup,kubernetesVersion:kubernetesVersion,dnsPrefix:dnsPrefix,servicePrincipalProfile:servicePrincipalProfile,agentPoolProfiles:agentPoolProfiles,networkProfile:networkProfile}" > aks-cluster-config.json`
3. Open the exported configuration file (aks-cluster-config.json) and update relevant fields such as location, resourceGroup, and other subscription-specific details with values from the target subscription.
4. Use the modified configuration file to create the AKS cluster in the target subscription.

   `az group create --name <target-resource-group> --location <target-location>`

   `az aks create --resource-group <target-resource-group> --name <aks-cluster-name> --subscription <target-subscription-id> --load-balancer-sku standard --enable-private-cluster --network-plugin azure --vnet-subnet-id <vnet-subnet-id> --service-cidr <service-cidr> --dns-service-ip <dns-service-ip> --docker-bridge-address <docker-bridge-address> --dns-prefix <dns-prefix> --enable-aad --aad-admin-group-object-ids <aad-admin-group-object-ids> --enable-managed-identity --node-resource-group <node-resource-group> --node-count <node-count> --node-vm-size <node-vm-size> --generate-ssh-keys`
5. Validate that the AKS cluster in the target subscription is functioning as expected.